# preg_replace is not removing all whitespace characters from string

Tags: php, preg-replace, whitespace

I've got the following code, which should be comparing 2 strings after stripping all the whitespace, here is a simplified version of the function:

```
function not_same($type, $org_str1, $str2) {

    $str1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $org_str1);
    $str2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str2);

    $tries = [];
    $tries[] = ["str1" => $str1, "str2" => $str2, "encoded1" => urlencode($str1), "encoded2" => urlencode($str2)];        

    if($str1 == $str2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I'm using this to check on a computer if the processor is the same as a matched model in my database, so `$org_str1` is what my client says the computer it is running on has, and `$str2` is the cpu in my database that the model should have.

Sometimes these strings have unneeded spaces, so during comparison I remove all of the whitspace so the text itself is compared.

Now I am getting computers back saying that the CPU is wrong, because the match is not made, because there is some whitespace that is not removed.

In this specific case, I'm trying to compare the string Client: `Celeron® N3050` vs Server: `Celeron®  N3050`.
I'm logging each time what is *actually* being compared on my server, on my client it says it is comparing Client: `Celeron® N3050` vs Server: `Celeron®N3050`

I tried copying and pasting this whitespace into a `str_replace()` function, but it did not solve the issue. After that, I got the idea of logging the string with `urlencode()`, this allows me to see exactly what this mysterious white character is, but I still am at a loss on how to fix the issue.

The strings after `urlencode()` are Client: `Celeron%C2%AE%C2%A0N3050` vs Server: `Celeron%C2%AEN3050`

As you can see, there is still a whitespace character in my client string, encoded to `%C2%A0`. Why does preg_replace not get rid of this whitespace, and how can I programmatically remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\xC2\xA0` is a unicode non-breaking space. Add the [`u` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to your regex.

```
$raw = urldecode('Celeron%C2%AE%C2%A0N3050');

var_dump(
    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $raw),
    preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $raw),
    urlencode($raw),
    urlencode(preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $raw))
);
```

Output:

```
string(16) "Celeron® N3050"
string(14) "Celeron®N3050"
string(24) "Celeron%C2%AE%C2%A0N3050"
string(18) "Celeron%C2%AEN3050"
```

Comment: Thank you! While waiting for an answer I was looking around for more information about this and also stumbled across something stating it was a non-breaking  space character, I was trying to find a way to remove non-breaking spaces but couldn't find anything as straightforward as your answer. I really appreciate it! Need some croutons for the side-dish of your sammitch?